# Installing software on CentOS without root

Tags: installation, root, yum, rpm

I realize variants of this question have been asked before. My question is why can't one have some kind of parallel directory structure where a user w/o root is able to install whatever they need? (Even chroot seems to require having root)

Is it impossible in principle?

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon how you are installing the software, you should be able to install it in a directory of your own such as `~/bin`.

Then you would edit ~/.bashrc (assuming bash is your shell) to add that to your path:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

Of course this will become more complex if you have dependencies and libraries to install.

As to how you would go about installing in `~/bin`. If you're building form source try `configure --help` for options, you may be able to do something like...

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin
make
make install
```

If you're installing from an RPM you'll most likely need to unpack the RPM manually since it's going to want to install files in places you don't have access to. There are some good answers as to the specifics of how to do that here, but it may not be for the faint of heart based upon the comments :-)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61283/yum-install-in-user-home-for-non-admins

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I know I could compile it from source or unpack the RPM...I was just wondering why there's no automatic utility to do that or atleast to fake a directory structure so RPM, etc can work normally